# Cant load content with AJAX call in IE8 - Javascript wont work

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have tried almost all the solutions for this issue, but it keeps killing me (and it is not killing softly ;) )

Here is a error details that IE8 reports :

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; AskTbPTV2/5.11.3.15590)

Timestamp: Mon, 18 Apr 2011 07:04:43 UTC


Message: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e.
Line: 265
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/omiccir/js/ajax_load.js

Message: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e.
Line: 265
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/omiccir/js/ajax_load.js
```

And this is my loadNews function :

```
function loadNews(id) {
xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp == null) {
    alert("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
    return;
}
var url = "news_show.jsp";
url = url + "?uuid=" + id;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getNewsOutput;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And here is line 265 :

```
263:    function getNewsOutput() {
264:    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
265:        document.getElementById("newsSpan").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
```

These functions are in a file named "ajax_load.js"

Is there anything wrong with my js functions? What should I do to fix this?

EDIT----

SOLVED!!

here is what i did to solve this issue , i opened a .txt file and saved it as utf-8, then copied the content of my jsp file (which was involved in this feature in this case "news_show.jsp") and pasted it into that .txt file, then click on save-as and saved it as jsp file and replaced the old one, and daaa daaaaaa , problem solved!!!

the sweet part is : although the jsp file was utf-8 from the beginning but doing the above procedure and utf-8ing! it this way , solved the problem!

oh god i hate IE ;)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to encoding. try to send the responce in utf-8 encoding so that the response header includes:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: thnx for reply , but i think it is not the problem, cause everything is utf8, and it works fine in all the other browsers

Comment: I am replying after doing search for this error code http://www.google.co.in/search?q=c00ce56e Most of the times when this error appeared, it was due to encoding.

Comment: Lucky!!! But still it's better to find out the reason for this as it may 'miraculously' come back. :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick google suggests that this is issue is to do with document encoding.

See if you can add appropriate UTF-8 headers to your response document using something like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Also make sure your webserver's configured correctly.

Comment: but it works swell in firefox, safari, chrome , and even my cellphones opera

Comment: all of my pages has <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %> and also all of them are utf8 document (saved as utf8) hmm, i dont know what else should i do :-?